# Awk inconsistent behavior filtering scientific notation numbers

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I recently found that for some very small values, filtering using AWK doesn't seem to behave correctly. As in the following file `test_loc.txt`:

```
10:10000018 10  0.4505
X:99997421  X   0.95508
X:99997626  X   0.016206
X:99998439  X   0.5043
10:100001724    10  0.69838
10:100001867    10  0.48936
2:137078930 2   2.8245e-05
10:100001868    10  0.11326
10:100002378    10  0.6674
19:45431453 19  3.952525e-323
10:100002464    10  0.87964
```

I want to filter by the third column, below some threshold. For instance:

```
awk '($3 < 0.5) {print $0}' test_loc.txt
```

yields

```
10:10000018 10  0.4505
X:99997626  X   0.016206
10:100001867    10  0.48936
2:137078930 2   2.8245e-05
10:100001868    10  0.11326
```

notably omitting the second to last entry, `19:45431453` with the very small column 3 value `3.952525e-323`.

However, when I threshold lower, at say `5e-5`:

```
awk '($3 < 5e-5) {print $0}' test_loc.txt
```

It picks it right up.

```
2:137078930 2   2.8245e-05
19:45431453 19  3.952525e-323
```

Any thoughts as to why and how I might get around this?

Comment: Type conversion rules? (Who gets converted, the string `$3` or the number `0.5`?) Try `awk '($3 + 0.0 < 0.5) {print $3}'` to make explicit that the left argument of `<` is a number.

Comment: If you're using GNU awk (gawk) you could also try adding the `-M` (`--bignum`) option, to enable GMP support

Comment: Works fine in `GNU Awk 5.0.1`, even without `-M`. Which version are you using?

Comment: @bu5hman my system is on awk 4.0.2, so that may be it.

Comment: @AlexP that worked like a charm! Thank you. I guess I need to take a closer look at awk type conversion rules.

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be reproduced on `awk` instances without MPFR or MP support for multiple precision. There is a limitation ~ `e-308` and `e+308` for very big or very small numbers.

See Table 16.1 here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computer-Arithmetic

See also: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/MPFR-features.html

You can find out if your `awk` supports multiple-precision from the output of `awk --version` (see above link). Also `-M` option will not work if only double precision is supported.

---

For example, for `GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0` without MPFR I run this example (not reproducible with awk 5)

```
$ cat file
1e-305
1e-306
1e-307
1e-308
1e-309
1e-310
$ awk '$0+0 > 0' file
1e-305
1e-306
1e-307
```

Note that `$0+0` evaluates to zero in case `$0` is a string that doesn't represent a valid number. Also any comparison like `$0>0` will be a string, not numeric, comparison for these cases.